# Google Assistant - askForPermission to get user email from google account

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When i try to connect google actions through google assistant i need to get user email id from google account to perform some Operations. For this i try to pops up message to get end user permission to get user email id from google account. The below message pops up when user try to access my actions.

“I’ll just need to get your email from Google account. Is that ok?”

If user says "yes" then will get user email id or if user says "no" it will reject.

My query is if user says "Thank you" or "fine" then also getting user email id. is it expected behavior? if any document link available for this please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.

Getting the user's email or other user details is handled via accountlinking. I assume you are using [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in) due to the dialogs that are used. The dialogs that are shown to your user when doing this are handled by Google.

Google has trained these dialogs quite well to make sure that the users details are only shared when the user agrees to it. If they answer the question with something unrelated, the dialog will reprompt automatically to make sure that user details are only shared if the user really means to do that.

The words "Thank you" and "Fine" are close enough to a Yes answer, so Google picks this up as a agreement to sharing the details.

Comment: Thanks Jordi for answering my query